# Passing a service in protobuf

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, rpc, proto, proto3

Suppose, I have a `Base` class and a `Foo` class derived from `Base`:

```
class Base {
}

class Foo : Base {
}
```

I'm writing the protobuf protocol to use their methods.

They share some functionality, is there a way to avoid rewriting code by passing the service?

For example:

```
service BaseProto {
   rpc SomeFunction (Request) returns (Response)
}

service FooProto {
   **Passing the service here instead of rewriting SomeFunction()
}
```

I'm working with C#, ProtoBuf 3.0.

Comment: Language? Proto version?

Comment: My bad, I've edited my massage.

Comment: Please verify my edit.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#services), it generates the interface code and stubs for the service. And, you are responsible for the implementation. `Foo` is inheriting its parent's behavior so I believe that you can easily use the shared functionality in your implementation.